# what programs can fxp a single file from the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp

I want to directly transfer one file from remote server A to remote server B from my local server. What programs can FXP a file using ftp other than lftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list of [ftp clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_client_software) and their supported protocols, including fxp and whether they are command line.